# How do I display the Var name of a variable instead of the value that Var hold in javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, text

So I am trying to build myself a debugger. Here is how I want the output to look:

```
kills:    7
level:    60
weapon:   sniper
```

These values will be displayed in a black rectangle that can be dragged around the screen using the mouse. Here is what is does so far. (I have cut out all visuals except the Text command) 
*Note: I am using Khan academy, so the code will look slightly different.*

```
var kills = 0; 
var level = 10;         
var weapon = 'sniper';

var input = [kills,level,weapon];  
var debug1 = function(data){
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i ++){
        text(data[i],mouseX + (i*30) + 4,mouseY - 75);
    }

};

var draw = function() {
    debug1(input); 
};
```

Code explanation: The Vars at the top are just sample Vars. I want debug1(){}; to be able to take any and all vars. 
What my output results look like (compare to what I want them to look like):

```
0
60
sniper
```

*My problem:* I cannot find a way to print out the bar *names* to the screen! In my formatted print I want the Var name associated with the data it holds. but whenever (and however) I try and print in the var *name* I always end up with its value. This makes my debugger useless, because even though it prints out values, I cant tell *what* vars the data is connected with. Please help me by showing a way to do this! Things I have tried:

```
data[i].text

"data[i]"
```

Comment: Make object, and you will have key:value structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you have the option of making the data an associative array 
i.e.

```
input = [Kills: kills, Level: level, Weapon: weapon]
```

so you can refer to them as Key/Val pairs?
You could then use something like

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    text(key + ': '+ value,mouseX + (i*30) + 4,mouseY - 75);
});
```

that could be one way to work it out (havent tested it yet, but it seems straight forward)